# Mac - how to authenticate `security find-generic-password` with Touch ID

Tags: security, keychain

I need to access the keychain on the command line with `security find-generic-password -ga`, which would prompt me for username and password for authentication, with or without sudo.

I already altered PAM config on my mac so that I can authenticate `sudo` with Touch ID - is it possible to authenticate `security find-generic-password` with Touch ID too?